# Creating a python executable in Linux with pyinstaller, fails to run in a Windows machine

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu-16.04, pyinstaller

I have written Python scripts on my Ubuntu machine, and would like to create executables to run them on Windows machines. I tested pyinstaller to create an executable by doing:

```
>>> pyinstaller myScript.py
```

The resulting /dist/myScript runs fine on the Ubuntu machinie it was created.

However when transfering the executable to a windows computer it won't run.
First of all, not having the .exe extension, windows does not even recognize it as an executable. 
After manually adding .exe and running on cmd:

```
>>> myScript.exe
```

the cmd spits: " This version of 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\myScript.exe' is not compatible with the version on Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher "

How can I solve this? Is this even the correct approach to create a python executable for windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only create an executable for your current operating system. 
So you would have to create your executable on windows for it to be an .exe.
You cannot simply change the file type to make it run on a different OS

Comment: So in order to create an executable for windows I would need to have a windows session with all installed dependencies needed in my script, run pyinstaller there, and then that executable would work on any windows machine?

Comment: That is correct!
You can do so in either a Windows VM or a native Windows desktop.
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

[Supporting Multiple Operating Systems](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#supporting-multiple-operating-systems) section in Pyinstaller highlights your usecase:

> If you need to distribute your application for more than one OS, for example both Windows and Mac OS X, you must install PyInstaller on each platform and bundle your app separately on each.